# how to get group host from inventory

Tags: ansible

I am trying to build an rsync type backup on multiple servers.  I would like to create a backup directory per server locally on my laptop and then back them up.  If the directory does not exist create it.
I start off by calling the playbook locally, so that I can create the directories locally, then change the playbook to the backup group.  The issue is that I dont know how to populate the hostnames in the backup group.  When I run the playbook below the only directory that gets created is localhost.  I need for each host in the backup group to create a local directory and back it up.  what would be the easiest way to make this work?

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  #strategy: free

  pre_tasks:

  vars:
   - backupDir: "/Users/user1/Desktop/Fusion/backups/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"

  roles:

  tasks:

  - name: Check if Backup Folder Exisits.
    stat:
      path: "{{ backupDir }}"
    register: my_folder

  - name: "Ansible Create directory if not exists"
    file:
      path: "{{ backupDir }}"
      state: directory
    when: my_folder.stat.exists == false

- hosts: backup
  tasks:

  - name: Rsync Directories from Remote to Local
    synchronize:
      mode: pull
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{ backupDir }}/{{ansible_date_time.date}}.back"
    with_items:
      - "/home/user1/"
      - "/var/www/html/"
      - "/root/"
    when: my_folder.stat.exists

  handlers:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, I think you're looking for the loop module.

something like this..

```
- name: "Ansible Create directory if not exists"
file:
  path: "{{ backupDir }}"
  state: directory
when: my_folder.stat.exists == false
loop: {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Answer (score 0):

In your inventory file you can create groups that tie back to your hosts you're calling on.

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1

[backup]
host1
host2
host3
```

Comment: I know that is exactly how I have my inventory setup.  What I need is to figure out how to call the backup hosts as a variable.  That way for each host in the backup group the backup will run an put the files in the correct place.

Comment: In that case, I think you're looking for the loop module.

something like this..

'- name: "Ansible Create directory if not exists"
    file:
      path: "{{ backupDir }}"
      state: directory
    when: my_folder.stat.exists == false'